# Bzr: Create a shared repository from an existing stand-alone repository

Tags: repository, bazaar, trunk

I have been using Bzr for version control of my project over the last few months. I am the sole developer, and currently I just have everything in a single local project directory, to which I commit and which I sync to DriveHQ.

I now have some large-scale experiments in mind which would likely break this main line, so I've been looking into the concepts of branches and shared repositories. So my question is, basically: how should I go about creating a new, shared repository from this already-version-controlled base?

I am familiar with the SVN project structure of trunk, branches and tags, and I'm going to adopt this structure. My plan is to just go ahead and do a fresh init-repo, and copy all my code (plus .bzr) over into the trunk folder. So is this OK? Or is there some way to convert what I have already into a shared repository?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Christopher

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, so you have some `work` directory where your standalone branch is.
You want to create `trunk` and feature branches in new shared repo.

At first you need to create a shared repository itself:

```
bzr init-repo /path/to/repo
```

Now you can put your code to `repo/trunk`. You can use `push`, `branch` or you can copy `work` and use `reconfigure`.

1. `cd work; bzr push /path/to/repo/trunk`
2. `cd path/to/repo; bzr branch /path/to/work trunk`
3. or copy/move `work` to `/path/to/repo/trunk` then `cd /path/to/repo/trunk; bzr reconfigure --use-shared`

In all cases you'll have branch `trunk` as a copy of your old `work`, and this `trunk` will use shared repository to save the revisions.

You can also look at [bzr-colo](https://launchpad.net/bzr-colo) plugin.

Comment: For me, I used #1 and it also worked perfectly (I think). I had same situation and used #1. To confirm, I `cd /path/to/repo`, where I type `bzr info` and get `Shared repository with trees (format: 2a)` (newline) `Location:` (newline) `shared repository: . ` . And then I type `bzr info trunk` which gives `Repository tree (format: 2a)` (newline) `Location:` (newline) `shared repository: . ` (newline) `repository branch: trunk ` . Thanks @bialix!

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a folder outside your current repository.
2. Call `bzr init-repo` to create a shared repository
3. From your working tree push to the newly created shared repo.

You can now work directly on the shared repo

Comment: I wanted to suggest  tha same but instead of push , do branch from the old rep to the new one. is there a difference?

Comment: @Gil: you can branch in the new shared repo from the old working copy, it works also.

Comment: @TridenT: Many thanks, very helpful. Just to clarify, can I then safely delete the old repository? And should I do that from Bzr, or can I just drag it to the trash?

Comment: @ChrisM Yes, once it is pushed, you can delete the old one.