# Bzr push error: diverged repositories after merge into main line

Tags: merge, repository, bazaar, merge-conflict-resolution

I have [very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462555/bzr-create-a-shared-repository-from-an-existing-stand-alone-repository) recently started using a Bzr shared repository to manage my project. I derived this by branching from a standalone repository to which I had been up to now making incremental commits. This new shared repository has a '/trunk, /branches' layout:

```
--xxxx_shared
  --trunk
    --src
    --lib
    --doc
  --branches
```

So I merged some changes from the trunk of this repository into the main line, but when I later attempted to push some further changes from the trunk I got an error stating that the two branches had diverged. I had committed the merge into the main line, and so there was a divergence. But how does one avoid this, given that one has to commit any merge? Or am I seriously misunderstanding things?

In order to resolve this conflict I merged from the main line BACK into the shared trunk branch. I suspect this was a mistake, since I now have a revision history for /xxxx_shared/trunk which looks like this:

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    revno: 74 [merge]
    committer: Chris <xxxxxxxx@yahoo.com>
    branch nick: trunk
    timestamp: Wed 2011-12-14 03:47:49 +0000
    message:
      Committing merge from parent branch.
        ------------------------------------------------------------
        revno: 71.1.1 [merge]
        committer: Chris <xxxxxxxx@yahoo.com>
        branch nick: mainline
        timestamp: Tue 2011-12-13 21:13:06 +0000
        message:
          Merged WinAPI toolbar updates from /projects/xxxx_shared/trunk.
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    revno: 73
    committer: Chris <xxxxxxxx@yahoo.com>
    branch nick: trunk
    timestamp: Wed 2011-12-14 03:33:35 +0000
    message:
      Updated the WinAPI toolbar button code...
```

So 71.1.1 above has been merged from the main line, and refers to the merge FROM /projects/xxxx_shared/trunk (shared repo) TO the main line.

I hope all this is clear. But how can I resolve this issue so as to recover a linear line of development? And what would be a conservative 'best practice' with Bzr so as to avoid this kind of thing in the future? I still have an unmodified copy of the original standalone repository, so I can always go back to that and start over again, if need be.

Comment: What do you mean by "main line"? Is it separate branch? Or is it supposed to be a copy of trunk branch?

Comment: FWIW, the layout of the repository isn't relevant in bzr - it's only the fact there are separate branches that matters.

Comment: @bialix - That's the original standalone repository from which the shared repository was branched.

Comment: @bialix - I don't do any work on this 'main line', it's more of a backup (it's synced to DriveHQ). I do incremental commits to the trunk of the shared repository, and more experimental, potentially breaking work in its branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have "main line" as exact mirror of the "trunk" you should only push from trunk to main line, or better pull from trunk into main line:

```
cd mainline
bzr pull /path/to/repo/trunk
```

If you have diverged branches situation then you need to use command `bzr missing` to understand why there is divergence occurs, after that merge to trunk, and execute the `pull` command above. Thus your main line will be exact copy of trunk.